# How to get webdriver instance to use same instance across all class files

Tags: singleton

I am new to java selenium.

I would like to use webdDrierSingleton concept, which will help me to use single driver instance across all classes.

I am not able to get the driver instance, could some one guide me how to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the singleton class by defining the class constructor as Private. Please have a look at the code below:

```java
public class InstanPage {

    private static InstanPage instance = null;
    private WebDriver driver;

    private InstanPage() {

    }

    public WebDriver openBrowser() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return driver;
    }

    public static InstanPage getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new InstanPage();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Your Test class:

```java
public class YourTestClass {

    private InstanPage automation = InstanPage.getInstance();
    private WebDriver driver;
    // this will give the comman instance of Browser.
    driver=automation.openBrowser();driver.get("WWW.XYZ.COM");

    @test
       public void testone()
       {
       // your test code
       }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sachin for your resonse.

Answer (score 5):

the singleton class:

```
public class WebDriverSingleton {

   public static WebDriver driver;

   public static WebDriver getInstance() {
     if (driver == null) {
       driver = new FirefoxWebDriver();
     }
     return driver;
   }

}
```

and in your test class:

```
WebDriver driver = WebDriverSingleton.getInstance();
```

Comment: class constructor is not made private. how its singleton pattern

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your test cases present in different classes then you can use @Guice

for example

ParentModule.class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import com.google.inject.Binder;
import com.google.inject.Module;

public class ParentModule implements Module{

@Override
public void configure(Binder binder) {
/** getDriver() is the method which is used for launching the respective browser, this method is written in SetDriver class */
    SetDriver setDriver = new SetDriver();
    WebDriver driver = setDriver.getDriver();
    binder.bind(WebDriver.class).toInstance(driver);
}
}
```

Example1.class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Guice;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import utility.ParentModule;

@Guice(modules = {ParentModule.class})
public class Example1 {

@Inject
WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("webdriver in Example1 class - " + driver);
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
}
}
```

Example2.class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Guice;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import utility.ParentModule;

@Guice(modules = {ParentModule.class})
public class Example2 {

@Inject
WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("webdriver in Example2 class - " + driver);
    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
}
}
```

TestNG.xml

```
<suite name="ABC">
<test name="Example">
    <classes>
        <class name="test.Example1"></class>
        <class name="test.Example2"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Note - for test cases to execute in single browser in testng.xml file we need to mention all the classes in single test