# How can i convert below Katalon Custom Keyword in to Selenium

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

Need to Convert below Katalon code into selenium, May I Know what area needs to be Converted?

```
package nasdaqKeyword
import ...


public class accesstoTable {

    private String table_date(String trid){

        return'/html[1]/body[1]/div[4]/div[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[' + trid + ']/th[1]';
    }

    private TestObject gettablevalueFirstcol(String trid){
        TestObject firstColu = new TestObject(trid);
        firstColu.addProperty("xpath", ConditionType.EQUALS,table_date(trid),true);
        return firstColu
    }

    @Keyword
    public String navigatetoGettablevalueFirstcol(String trid){
        TestObject firstColu = gettablevalueFirstcol(trid);
        WebUI.waitForElementPresent(firstColu,GlobalVariable.time_1)
        String abc = WebUI.getText(firstColu)
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Katalon uses Groovy as the programming language under the hood and all the Katalon keywords are basically Groovy wrappers around Selenium code.

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836655/how-to-convert-katalon-script-in-selenium-java) and [this article](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/using_selenium_webdriver_katalon_studio.html#introduction) for more details on particulars.