# How to run Katalon script from simple java application?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, katalon-studio

#### Goal

Execute scripts produced with Katalon Studio, using java. If this works, scripts could run on my devops pipeline: browserstack or my own selenium server.

#### Problem

I have this groovy script which is the same as Katalon studio produced scripts:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
WebUI.openBrowser("https://www.katalon.com")
```

I tried to run this script using java maven project. I achieved to find all the required jars. But when I run I get this error: **java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to open browser with url: 'https://www.katalon.com'
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:26)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.openBrowser(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.execute(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:67)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:73)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.openBrowser(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:63)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$openBrowser.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:17)
    at JenkinsGroovySandbox1.main(JenkinsGroovySandbox1.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/kms/katalon/core/webui/driver/DriverFactory.createNewRemoteWebDriver(Ljava/util/Map;Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; @168: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'io/appium/java_client/remote/AppiumCommandExecutor' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'org/openqa/selenium/remote/HttpCommandExecutor'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @168
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/util/Map', 'org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'com/kms/katalon/core/network/ProxyInformation', 'java/lang/Object', 'io/appium/java_client/remote/AppiumCommandExecutor' }
    stack: { uninitialized 161, uninitialized 161, 'io/appium/java_client/remote/AppiumCommandExecutor', 'org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: b800 f04d b802 a54e 2dc7 0006 1236 4eb8
    0x0000010: 020a 3a04 1904 b602 0e99 0014 2bb8 02a8
    ...
    0x00000e0: bf                                     
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@15,Object[#154],Object[#154])
    append_frame(@45,Object[#527])
    same_frame(@98)
    append_frame(@119,Object[#3])
    same_frame(@142)
    same_frame(@172)
    same_frame(@202)

    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword$_openBrowser_closure1.doCall(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:74)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword$_openBrowser_closure1.call(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:20)
    ... 7 more
```

#### Theories

**RemoteWebDriver**

As we can see in the log, by default katalon libraries are using **remote web driver with Appium**. I can't find how to setup the webdriver in this script using katalon libraries. With pure selenium is very easy :D

I'm researching the possibility to use Local driver instead remote driver or how to configure the parameters in my simple groovy script to use my remote driver.

**Katalon Community vs Enterprise**

Maybe katalon scripts are supposed to be executed using Katalon tools, not from outside katalon tools.

#### Attempts

- [How to convert Katalon Script in Selenium Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836655/how-to-convert-katalon-script-in-selenium-java)

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I achieved to run any katakon script with java and maven. All of that on linux. This is what I did:

**1.- load several katakon jars** to my pom. They are not public (early 2021) so the only why was extract them from the katalon studio installation.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>katalon</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.kms.katalon.core_1.0.0.202101180916.jar</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${katalon.studio.home.path}/plugins/com.kms.katalon.core_1.0.0.202101180916.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

**2.- Modify one katalon class due to new errors**. The only solution was to delete one method of one class from katalon source code which is public:

original: https://github.com/katalon-studio/katalon-studio-testing-framework

modified: https://github.com/jrichardsz-software-architect-tools/katalon-runner/blob/beta/src/main/java/com/kms/katalon/core/testobject/ObjectRepository.java#L263

Here is my project wich I called: katalon-runner.

https://github.com/jrichardsz-software-architect-tools/katalon-runner

The execution flow is:

- clone and build the katalon runner
- record the ui flow with katalon to obtain the groovy scripts
- using the shell, execute the katalon-runner passing it several parameters

As you see this has a plugin nature, so it is easy to use on Jenkins or any ci server.

Pd: I have some local changes. I will update the repository.